# Neo4j Clean build failed on IntelliJ Idea

Tags: neo4j

I've imported fresh unchanged neo4j sources using pom.xml in IntelliJ Idea and tried to compile it for the first time. Unfortunately there is 71 errors and thousands of of warnings.

If I run "mvn clean install" from command line it works just fine without errors. OSX

`Information:Using Eclipse compiler to compile java sources
Information:31/12/2015, 13:15 - Compilation completed with 71 errors and 9,371 warnings in 9m 7s 9ms
(..)
    Error:Error:line (101)java: Void methods cannot return a value
    Error:Error:line (100)java: The method executeAndCommit(java.util.function.Consumer) is ambiguous for the type 
BatchInsertTest.java
    Error:Error:line (1,723)java: The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
LuceneLabelScanStoreExtension.java
    Error:Error:line (37)java: Internal error: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Resource already created : CLASS_OUTPUT//META-INF/services/
community/kernel/src/test/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/api/store/StorePropertyPayloadCursorTest.java
    Error:Error:line (118)java: The method newCursor(org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.StorePropertyPayloadCursorTest.Param[]) is ambiguous
Error:(47, 1) java: Internal error: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Resource already created : CLASS_OUTPUT//META-INF/services/org.neo4j.shell.App`

Can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong?

I've updated my jdk to build 65 because I read that lambda ambiguities caused compile errors on early Java8 builds but it didn't remove ambiguity errors.

So far I can see I'm experiencing few kinds of errors:

*lamba expressions ambiguities (adding a cast helps but then IDEA says cast is redundant, if I remove casting there's a compile error...)
*errors on annotation `@Service.Implementation( App.class )` Resource already created : CLASS_OUTPUT//META-INF/services/org.neo4j.shell.App

Comment: Can you please only post the relevant parts of the log output. Nobody is going to read through 1000 lines of a poorly formatted log.

Comment: Sorry about long log output. It's long list and most of errors seem to be errors if I look into source code. But then why does it compile from command line?

Comment: Is your IntelliJ project using the right Java version and/or language level? I think the master branch will require JDK8.

Comment: Yes it is for sure. I'm using Java8 version and language level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Java Compiler option "Use compiler" from "Eclipse" compiler to "Javac".